# How does java check version online

Tags: java, applet, versions, url

i'd like to know how does java check his version when facing an applet online. Does it phonecalls a particular site? How can i get that site?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check to ensure that you have the recommended version of Java installed for your operating system: http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd like to know if java checks its version on a particular site when accessing an applet

Comment: @AlessandroAggio If you use Google Chrome or Chromium browser, for sure java checks its version: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181003?hl=en. And maybe this link is useful for your question: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/browser_activate_plugin.xml